# Magento 2.4.2 There is no Customer Tax Class

Tags: magento2, customer, tax, tax-class, tax-rule

There is no customer tax class in magento 2.4.2 Stores > Tax Rule. How to enable the tax classes.[image]

The configuration inside the Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax

[image]

Comment: check below link https://magefan.com/blog/magento-2-tax-configuration configure as explained

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are like me and totally forget that there is this really annoying little symbol on the right of "Additional Settings" that means it is a dropdown? I always forget
[image: annoying little symbol]

When you click it, it opens up a whole world of possibilities. You can add as many classes as you like and enable or this able them as you wish.
[image]